# TR background not working properly

Tags: html, css, html-table

I made a table and this is working fine, but I want to add background in few `TR`, but this is not working properly as I want. See the below code for what I tried to do this. Can anybody  solve it?

```css
    .table{ border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px;}
    .table tr:nth-child(1), .table tr:nth-child(2), .table tr:nth-child(3){ background: #ccc; padding: 20px;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

What I want see is shown in the below picture:-

[image]

Comment: I dont see whats wrong or what you want

Comment: have you seen picture which i shared as i want

Actually i want to add background in just 4 row like in light green picture

Comment: Still unclear what exactly you want. Do you want a black border around the top 4 rows with a separate background colour to the rest of the table?

Comment: Can't be done. Use two tables.

Comment: @wickywills I want table should be like this "https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsNST.jpg%22%22" first 4th TR should be with different background.

Comment: @RohitVerma Sorry but you're still not making sense here. You're stating "4th TR should be different background", but in your image, the 4th row has the darker green background just like the other rows above it! The answer provided below exactly answers your question as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

No need of using `.table tr:nth-child(1), .table tr:nth-child(2), .table tr:nth-child(3)`. You can target the first 4 rows of your table using `nth-child(-n+4)` like below.

```css
.table tbody tr:nth-child(-n+4) {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: did you mean the remaining rows should have light background and only the first 4 rows should have some dark background.

Comment: simply saying not same, better to explain what is not same??